# Subquery inside whereIn

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I need to create a little bit more complicated query. In first step I have to select Galleries which belongs to User model from array (I use whereIn to solve this problem) and I have to filter this results. I'm using where and orWhere to this. It looks like this:

```
return Galleries::whereIn('user_id',
                             $this->myMethod()
                             ->get()
                             ->pluck('id')
                            )
                 ->where('something', 0)
                 ->orWhere('somethingElse', 1)
                 ->orwhere(function($query) {
                    /* Other my code*/
                    );
                 })
                ->limit($limit);
```

}
Problem is that my results is not correct. If I have only whereIn, it display correct profiles but without filters. If I add where and OrWhere it displays User's profile which are not visible in this array. Could you help me? How can I use where and orWhere to result of whereIn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a wrong data because your query more like

```
SELECT * FROM Galleries WHERE user_id in (ids) and something = 0 or somethingElse = 1 or blabla...
```

You can try to move your filtering code into a where with callback function

```
Galleries::whereIn('user_id',
                         $this->myMethod()
                         ->get()
                         ->pluck('id')
                        )
             ->where(function($query){
                    $query->where('something', 0)
                    ->orWhere('somethingElse', 1)
                    ->orwhere(function($query) {
                          /* Other my code*/
                      
                    });
             })
            ->limit($limit);
```

The sql statement will be like

```
SELECT * FROM Galleries WHERE user_id in (ids) and (something = 0 or somethingElse = 1 or blabla...)
```